# How to convert hex to string or text in php

Tags: php, string, converters

I want to encrypt a message to string(text) format but I don't know the function which can convert Hex to String:

here is my page :

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

// on commence par définir la fonction Cryptage que l'on utilisera ensuite
        function Cryptage($TEXT, $Clef) {
            $LClef = strlen($Clef);
            $LTEXT = strlen($TEXT);
            if ($LClef < $LTEXT) {
                $Clef = str_pad($Clef, $LTEXT, $Clef, STR_PAD_RIGHT);
            } elseif ($LClef > $LTEXT) {
                $diff = $LClef - $LTEXT;
                $_Clef = substr($Clef, 0, -$diff);
            }
            return bin2hex($TEXT ^ $Clef);
        }

        /* On vérifie l’existence de $_POST['TEXT'] et de $_POST['Clef'].
          Ça revient au même que isset($_POST['TEXT']) AND isset($_POST['Clef']) */
        if (isset($_POST['TEXT'], $_POST['Clef'])) {
            $resultat = Cryptage($_POST['TEXT'], $_POST['Clef']);
        }

// on a fini les traitement en PHP, on passe à l'affichage :

        if (isset($resultat)) {
            echo "Chaîne cryptée/décryptée : " . $resultat;
        }
        ?>

        <!-- on affiche le formulaire pour que l'utilisateur puisse directement refaire un cryptage/décryptage -->
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="TEXT" style="width:500px" value="Cliquez ici pour ajouter un texte." onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" />
            <input type="text" name="Clef" style="width:500px" value="Cliquez ici pour ajouter un masque." onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crypter/Décrypter" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tested this function but it doesn't return anything (it returns an empty string)

```
  function hextostr($hex)
{
$str='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
{
$str .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
}
return $str;
}
```

do you have any idea, thanks

Comment: You'd better translate your french code comment into english one...

Answer (score 4):

```
  function hex2str($hex) {
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2)
       $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2)));

    return $str;
  }
```

Will do the trick

Comment: I just test it but it doesn't work, it returrn an empty string

Comment: which hex are you passing to the function

Comment: this string doesn't have valid chars. And it has a 0x00 in the middle

Comment: This answer is correct, given code works as expected to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function hex2str($func_string) {
$func_retVal = '';
$func_length = strlen($func_string);
for($func_index = 0; $func_index < $func_length; ++$func_index) $func_retVal .= chr(hexdec($func_string{$func_index} . $func_string{++$func_index}));

return $func_retVal;
}
```

I use this one a lot personally so it should work.

Comment: this one also, I tested it but doesn't work, it return an empty string

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`hex2bin()`

That'll convert your hex to a string format.