# What is the PHP equivalent of MySQL's UNHEX()?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the PHP equivalent of MySQL's UNHEX()?

For instance, the following query and PHP function should provide the same value.

```
SELECT UNHEX(c1) AS unhexed_c1 FROM table;

$unhexed_c1=PHPs_UNHEX_Equivalent($c1);
```

Comment: This is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488538/convert-hex-to-ascii-characters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a built-in function called [hex2bin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) if you're running PHP >= 5.4.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with [`pack`](http://php.net/pack):

```
$unhexed = pack('H*', $hexstring);
```

Comment: Why pack instead of hex2bin (assuming you are running PHP 5.4 or greater)?

Comment: In the time of writing this answer, most hosting companies that I have used were stuck with php 5.3.x. Even now many popular frameworks / cms / blog platforms targets php 5.3 or even 5.2, so my answer was not assuming that.

Answer (score 5):

See [How to convert hex to string or text in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346119/how-to-convert-hex-to-string-or-text-in-php):

```
  function unhex($hex) {
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2)
       $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2)));

    return $str;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think  you  look for [hex2bin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php)